# Node.js зачем-то компилирует SVG файл

Tags: node.js, svg, typescript

У меня есть проект, в котором есть svg, два собранных React приложения и стартовый скрипт с express сервером index.ts.

`index.ts`:

```
const path = require('path')

const mainRouter = require('./routers/main.router.ts')
const authRouter = require('./routers/auth.router.tsx')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const intel = require('intel');
const alpha = intel.getLogger('prettynotes');
alpha.setLevel(intel.INFO)

require('dotenv').config()

app.use('/', mainRouter)
app.use('/auth', authRouter)

let server = app.listen(process.env.LOCALPORT, () => {
    let address = 'localhost'
    if(server.address().address == '::'){
        address = 'localhost:' + server.address().port
    }
    else{
        address = server.address().address + server.address().port
    }
    if(process.env.MODE === "DEVELOPMENT") alpha.warn(`Warning! Current mode is ${process.env.MODE}. In production you must change .env variable 'MODE' to 'PRODUCTION'.`)
    alpha.info(`Server started successfully. Server running at address http://${address}`)
})
```

При запуске командой:
`ts-node index.ts`
я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
D:\MyPrettyFolder\src\clients\common-assets\logo.svg:1
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.8 28.96">
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Pretty Notes Project\Pretty Notes\src\clients\authclient\components\Login.tsx:6:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

То есть `ts-node` зачем-то пытается компилировать icon.svg. Как исправить эту ошибку? Или как ограничить доступ к папке с иконками?

Answer (score 0):

> То есть ts-node зачем-то пытается компилировать icon.svg. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Ну в подключаемых файлах видимо используется `icon.svg`, а точнее `logo.svg`. Поэтому он при сборке, проходит по ним. `ts-node` не умеет работать с подобным типом файлов. К примеру можно использовать `webpack`.

Ссылка на настройку https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, ошибка та же самая.

Comment: @АлексейБобрович изначально перепутал ошибку, вам нужен `webpack` как сборщик, чтобы можно было обрабатывать другого типа файлы.

Comment: у меня webpack как раз задействован в проекте. Он собирает React приложения.

Comment: @АлексейБобрович тогда надо смотреть `webpack.config.js` и запускать не `node-ts`, а `webpack` для сборки

Comment: но ts-node с index.ts для сервера. Index.ts не собирает, запускает express сервер

Comment: @АлексейБобрович лучше вебпаком все собрать и потом node server.js запускать

Comment: Я так и делаю: сначала собираю приложения, потом запускаю сервер.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126717/discussion-between---and-maxkrasnov).